# Lock a choice in PyQt4 QComboBox using a QCheckBox

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4, qcombobox, qcheckbox

I am beginning to write a GUI using `PyQt4`. This is my first experience with GUIs (and also oo-programming is somewhat new to me). Part of that GUI will be like 4 to 5 instances of `QComboBox`. As many choices are to be made, I want the user to be able to lock a choice, such that is not being changed unintenionally later. For one QComboBox I can solve the problem with this code that I wrote:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyGui(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.resize(250, 50)

        # vertical layout for widgets
        self.vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

        # Create a combo box with some choices
        self.combo_color = QtGui.QComboBox()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.combo_color)
        items = 'Red Yellow Purple'.split()
        self.combo_color.addItems(items)
        self.connect(self.combo_color, QtCore.SIGNAL('activated(QString)'), self.use_choice)

        # add a checkbox next to the combobox which (un-)locks the the combo-choice
        self.checkbox_color = QtGui.QCheckBox('Lock Choice', self)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.checkbox_color)
        self.connect(self.checkbox_color, QtCore.SIGNAL('stateChanged(int)'), self.lock_choice)

    def use_choice(self, text):
        # do something very useful with the choice
        print 'The current choice is: {choice}'.format(choice=text)

    def lock_choice(self):
        if self.checkbox_color.isChecked():
            self.combo_color.setEnabled(False)
            print 'Choice {choice} locked'.format(choice=self.combo_color.currentText())
        else:
            self.combo_color.setEnabled(True)
            print 'Choice unlocked'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mygui = MyGui()
    mygui.show()
    app.exec_()
```

This code does what it should, but I am very unhappy with its design, because the method `lock_choice` is hard-coded to only lock the choice of the QComboBox `combo_color`. What if I now want to do the same thing for another QComboBox (say `combo_name`) and a second QCheckBox (say `checkbox_name`) which could be realized by appending the following code to the classes `__init__(self)` code block:

```
    # create second combo box with some other choices
    self.combo_name = QtGui.QComboBox()
    self.vbox.addWidget(self.combo_name)
    items = 'Bob Peter'.split()
    self.combo_name.addItems(items)
    self.connect(self.combo_name, QtCore.SIGNAL('activated(QString)'), self.use_choice)

    # add a checkbox next to the combobox which (un-)locks the the combo-choice
    self.checkbox_name = QtGui.QCheckBox('Lock Choice', self)
    self.vbox.addWidget(self.checkbox_name)
    self.connect(self.checkbox_name, QtCore.SIGNAL('stateChanged(int)'), self.lock_choice) # <-- obviously wrong, as it (un-)locks color choice at the moment
```

Both QComboBoxes can share the method `use_choice()` right now, but they cannot share the method `lock_choice()`, as both checkboxes lock the color-choice. I want the checkbox `checkbox_name` to lock the name-choice, without copy and pasting the current  `lock_choice()`-method and switching the hardcoded combobox.
I am sure there is an easy way, like passing the target-combobox to the method, which i just don't know yet. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try partial functions-

```
from functools import partial
```

with the connect signal, pass the QWidget name:

```
self.connect(self.checkbox_color, QtCore.SIGNAL('stateChanged(int)'), partial(self.lock_choice, self.combo_color))
```

And in your method, you may add an argument.

We'll add an argument in the method like below, to handle the QWidget(QComboBox) that we'll pass through the partial function above.

```
def lock_choice(self, combos):
    if combos.isEnabled(True):
        combos.setEnabled(False)
        print 'Choice {choice} locked'.format(choice=combos.currentText())
```

Comment: Can please you expand your answer by explaining the "you may add an argument"-part? This seems to be what i am looking for.

Comment: Tnanks, I see what you mean. The current version, however, has a bug as the line ``if combos.isChecked():`` raises the ``AttributeError: 'QComboBox' object has no attribute 'isChecked'``, which makes sense since it should be the checkbox, which is checked for ``isChecked()``. Would you suggest passing the correct checkbox as argument as well or is there another way?

Comment: for QComboBox, you may use if combos.isEnabled(True).

Comment: for QCheckBox also you may pass it using the partial functions, the same way we did for QComboBox.

Comment: Both ways are fine. It works with: ``self.connect(self.checkbox_name, QtCore.SIGNAL('stateChanged(int)'), partial(self.lock_choice, self.combo_name, self.checkbox_name))`` and in the lock_choice-method: ``def lock_choice(self, combos, checkbox):`` followed by: ``if checkbox.isChecked():``. Learned something here. Thanks, +1.

Comment: Last question: is ``partial()`` still the correct way to go? All arguments are passed over now. Couldn't something with ``map()`` also do the job?

Comment: There is another way, you can try QSignalMapper, but it gets complicated for me...partial() is easy and ofcourse correct...you may explore [QSignalMapper Class](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to use the [toggled](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#toggled) signal with the [setDisabled](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setDisabled) slot:

```
    self.checkbox_color.toggled.connect(self.combo_color.setDisabled)
```

(And note how much cleaner the [new-style sytax](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) is when making signal connections).

It's also worth pointing out that you can also use a `lambda` for making inline signal connections, like this:

```
    self.checkbox_color.toggled.connect(
        lambda checked: self.combo_color.setDisabled(checked))
```

This is probably the most idiomatic solution when there are no convenient signal/slot pairings (and of course partial functions can achieve more or less the same thing in different way).

Comment: That really does look cleaner, i will give it a try later.